# Recharts line chart - hide line values that are 0

Tags: recharts

How can I hide the lines along the bottom x-axis? See how the x axis line is covered with the coloured lines? I would like to not cover the x axis line with these 0 values.

[image]

Comment: One way would be to preprocess your raw data and replace all the zeroes that are not adjacent to a non-zero value with -1. Then plot with the y-scale forced to [0.0 ..1.6k].

Comment: On Recharts I have no idea but on every other graphics package I have used you can (0.01 might be worth a try too)